# Finding the probability of a fraction being in lowest terms.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Need help with the following problem,

a) One of the numbers 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12 and 13 is chosen at random as the numerator of a fraction, and then one of the remaining numbers is chosen at random as the denominator of the fraction. What is the probability of the fraction being in lowest terms?

I know I need to get the number of elements in the event (fraction in lowest terms) over the number of elements in the sample space to find the probability, but I'm not sure which counting techniques I need to use to find the cardinality of each these sets.

Comment: The size of the sample space can be done using counting techniques. The number of elements in the event has to be done by brute force.

Comment: Looks easy: just list the fractions which fail (top and bottom both even).

Comment: In this case there is no way that's simpler than just listing all the possible fractions and counting.

Answer (score 1):

The fraction is in lowest terms unless both top and bottom are even. Total number of fractions is 56. Total number with top and bottom both enen is 20. So prob of lowest terms is 9/14.

Answer (score 0):

You can work out all possible fractions using combinations.
You firstly choose one of the eight numbers:
$${8\choose1}$$
(8 choose 1)
Then you choose the next number, out of seven:
$$7\choose1$$
(7 choose1)
Multiply these to get:
$${8\choose1} \times {7\choose1} = 56$$
There are 56 combinations.

Then, for all the even numbers as denominators, if you choose any other even numerator, it will divide down. This will help us find how many fractions do simplify. If you choose an odd number for the numerator, it won't and if you choose an odd denominator it won't simplify down.

The number of fractions which do simplify (even/even) are:
P(choose even)*P(Choose even again)
$$\frac{5}{8}\times\frac{4}{7} = \frac{5}{14}$$
$$\frac{5}{14}\times56 = 20$$
20 out of 56 simplify, so 36 out of 56 don't, so the answer is:
$$\frac{36}{56}=\frac{9}{14}$$
Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

We have $\dbinom{8}2=28$ sets of numbers and try to find the chance the values in the set are prime (complementary count).
Note that the only shared factors are of $2$ and $3.$ Therefore, it must be one of those factors that are shared.
If it shares $2,$ there are $5$ values $(2,4,6,8,12)$ that might be in a set to make $\dbinom52=10$ sets.
If it shares $3,$ there are $2$ values $(6,12)$ that might be in a set to make $\dbinom22=1$ set.
However, we have overcounted. The sets that are complete with only the values $(6,12),$ which consists of $1$ set, has been overcounted. We subtract it from our total number of sets.
There are $10+1-1=10$ sets, and $28$ possible sets for a total of $\frac{10}{28}=\frac5{14}$ chance of not being simplified.
Therefore, it has a $1-\frac5{14}=\boxed{\frac{9}{14}}$ chance of being simplified.